# How do I fix SVC-FILWRT on Windows?

Tags: marklogic

I have to do some processing (enhancing metadata) on the XML document that are on my Marklogic database. For that I have created a new HTTP server that is pointing towards the database. Using that HTTP server, I write a XQuey that loop through all the XML documents in Marklogic database and send these XML documents to particular URL that reads the content from that document, append some metadata and then store back to ML.

This is something I have tried on Linux platform with same version of Marklogic and it works great for me. But now, when I am trying the same on window platform (Windows 7 Enterprise addition) and it's not working.

Approaches I tried to resolve that:

1. Running Marklogic Server as "Run as Administrator".
2. Putting HTTP server's Base directory into D:/ directory i.e. directory that does not have windows installed within it.
3. Above same with putting forest to D:/ directory.

The error on windows is:

```
XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest Security not available:
XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in startup of forest Security:
SVC-FILWRT:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SVC-FILWRT` is a filesystem write error. According to https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/messages/SVC-en#SVC-FILWRT it may mean that the filesystem is full. Check on that: I'd want to have a few GB free. If the drive is full then you may need to uninstall MarkLogic and reinstall it on another drive.

Otherwise I think `SVC-FILWRT` can also be a permissions error. MarkLogic may be running as a user that does not have permission to write to `%DATA_DIRECTORY%/Forests/Security`. In that case figure out what `%DATA_DIRECTORY%` is on your system, and ensure that MarkLogic process has permission to create subdirectories and write files in that directory.

If there is any more of the error message after `SVC-FILWRT`, that might help.